# Trouble fetching from multiple models in backbone

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

I'm working on an app in node.js using backbone and am having trouble understanding how to go about pulling in data from two models that are related to one another.  In this case I have a model Users and a model Comments, and on the user view I want to show some of the user data as well as a list of the user's comments. I've tried doing a multiple fetch statement (not sure if this is the right direction), but it's only returning the data in an object array and not under the attributes object that backbone requires.

Here's the function from the backbone router that I'm trying to work with:

```
showUser: function(id) {
  var user = new User({id: id});
  var comments = new Comments({userId: id});
  $.when(user.fetch(), comments.fetch())
    .done(function(userdata, commentdata) {
      window.showUserView = new showUserView({
        model: userdata,
        data: commentdata
      });
    });
```

What is the preferred method of pulling data from multiple models / collections in backbone?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what's the relation between the 2 models? If user *has many* comments?

Comment: It's normal, what you are getting here is the ajax response

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to accomplish this, but the best one (in my point of view) is :

Split your view into two views (UserView & UserCommentsView), in each view add this method :

```
initialize : function() {
   this.model.bind('change', 'render');
}
```

After that, change your router as :

```
showUser: function(id) {
    var user = new User({id: id});
    var comments = new Comments({userId: id});

    new UserView({ model: user });
    new UserCommentsView({ model: comments });

    user.fetch();
    comments.fetch();
}
```